# Someone says "150" in "a fifty"?

Tags: spoken-english, numbers

I know English people prefer to say "3-digit-number" in "N 2-digit" form. But I unexpected that 150 can be said as "a fifty". That sounds like just fifty.
I heard this from the American TV series *Unforgettable* - S01E16.

[image: Screencap captioned "Wow. Nobody shows and the ystill charge you $150"]

Comment: @choster, I heard it from <<Unforgetable>>.

Comment: If you want to post a video (or audio clip) we might be able to say something more useful.  I just watched a different clip from this episode and found that the lead actress does not have a very good American accent.  She's from Australia and I could hear Australianisms in her speech. If she did indeed say "a fifty" it might just be that she hasn't mastered the American accent, and thought this sounded correct.

Comment: It is worth remembering that conversation in a TV drama is not spontaneous - it is scripted (written beforehand), and, of course, rehearsed, and spoken by actors, who may mumble or deliver their words badly. The script says '$150'.

Comment: Are you sure he isn't saying 'one-fifty'? And maybe with a heavy accent?

Comment: The only sense I can think of where "a fifty" is idiomatic is as meaning "a single fifty-dollar bill."

Comment: $150 is never spoken as "a fifty". In some AAVE dialects it might be pronounced with a somewhat nasal "one" and the /f/ gone from "fifty" :  uhn fitty.

Comment: I'm willing to be that if I heard the line, I would not hear *a fifty*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are some contexts where we would read 150 as "one fifty," but many contexts in which we'd prefer "one hundred and fifty" or "one hundred fifty" and even some contexts where we'd prefer "one five zero."

In any case, we sometimes pronounce 100 as "a hundred," but we never pronounce 1 as "a."  Thus, we might say "a hundred and fifty" or "a hundred fifty," but never "a fifty" (only "one fifty") and never "a five zero."